# What does "give/shoot someone a sharp look" mean?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, sentence-meaning

> She gave/shot him a sharp look.

1. What does "sharp" mean in this context?
2. Is it a normal word to use in this kind of context?

Comment: When you looked up “sharp” in the dictionary, what did you find, and why didn’t that help?

Answer (score 2):

It's a metaphor. *Sharp* is used to describe objects:

> having a thin edge or point ***that can cut*** something or make a hole in something ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sharp))

Used metaphorically, this word can be used to express gestures or words:

> intended to be strong enough to be felt as painful:
>
> - Leonard has a ***sharp*** tongue (= often speaks in a severe and critical way).

Yes, ***sharp look*** is a common expression. Macmillan gives an example with it to explain ***sharp***:

> a sharp comment, voice, or expression shows that someone is unfriendly or annoyed
>
> - My father shot her a sharp look but said nothing. ([Macmillan](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/sharp_1))

***NOTE***: The verb ***shoot*** adds to the metaphor, comparing the *look* to a *bullet*.